# Why does not command os.system("doskey /history") work?

Tags: python, windows, console-application, nuitka

I have a Python script for *Windows* that prompts the user for input. I want the script to have the ability to clear all previous user prompts and their history, but my code doesn't work properly.

To achieve this, I am trying the following code:

```
os.system("cls")
os.system("doskey /history")
os.system("doskey /reinstall")
```

Command with "cls" works fine, but lines with "doskey" doesn't.
I'm not sure if it will be important or not, but I have compiled this script into an exe using the Nuitka compiler, so it runs as a Windows console application.

Comment: Can you add more details as to why it isn't working? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Actually, there are no errors. The reason it doesn't work is that when I press the up and down arrows on the keyboard, I can still see all of my previous inputs. This behavior is strange because I expected it to be the vice versa

Comment: Each `os.system` will create and open a new shell and it execute the command there. so they are all detached to actual terminal

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thank you for answer. According to the Python documentation, you are correct. It states: 'Execute the command (a string) in a subshell.' However, I wonder, why does the command os.system("cls") work for my current shell at the same time?

Comment: Ok, things are more complex. "subshell" share same terminal of python (and the mail shell). `cls` send commands to the terminal: it is executed on a different "environment", but the command tell the window to "clean". The other commands just execute and exit. I think stdout is detached (note: usually we use `subprocess` module to have more control.